# .NET Core 2 & DI - use values from appsettings.json in the constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

how to use the constructor parameters, whose values are stored in the `appsettings.json` ?

```
services.AddTransient<IService, Service>(x => new Service("arg1", "arg2"));
```

I use the `IOptions` interface to read my config values

```
services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MyOptions)));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If using `IOptions<T>` then update `Service` constructor to explicitly depend on `IOptions<MyOptions>` so that it can be injected into the class.

```
public class Service: IService {    
    public Service(IOptions<MyOptions> options) {
        this.arg1 = options.Value.arg1;
        this.arg2 = options.Value.arg2;
    }
}
```

Configuration can be simplified to

```
services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MyOptions)));
services.AddTransient<IService, Service>();
```

Assuming *appsettings.json* contains

```
{
   "MyOptions": {
       "arg1": value1,
       "arg2": value2
    }
}
```

If unable to change service class constructor then resolve option in object factory delegate

```
services.AddTransient<IService, Service>(serviceProvider => {
    var options = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<MyOptions>>();
    return new Service(options.Value.arg1, options.Value.arg2);
});
```

Reference [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: `IOptions<T>` is unnecessary, since the OP utilized `services.Configure`. That means they can inject `MyOptions` directly now. There is benefit in injecting `IOptionsSnapshot<T>`, as that gets you reload functionality, but given that the OP is adding a transient service, anyways, even that is superfluous.

Comment: @ChrisPratt That makes sense. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter in the lambda for that overload of `AddTransient` you're using is actually an instance of `IServiceProvider`. That means you can simply do:

```
services.AddTransient<IService, Service>(p => {
    var options = p.GetRequiredService<MyOptions>();
    return new Service(options.arg1, options.arg2);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values from appsettings.json with the frameworks IConfiguration interface.

Lets say your json is

```
{
   "argSection": 
    {
       "arg1": 1,
       "arg2": 2
    }
}
```

Then read the values like this

```
services.AddTransient<IService, Service>(x => new Service(Configuration["argSection:arg1"], Configuration["argSection:arg2"]));
```